# onReceive EVENT_REMINDER

Tags: android, events, calendar

I have created a broadcastreceiver to hook calendar EVENT_REMINDER and to get info about event

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    bReceiver = new HealtDroidBroadcastReceiver();
    IntentFilter inf = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER");
    inf.addDataScheme("content");
    inf.addDataAuthority("com.android.calendar",null);
    registerReceiver(bReceiver,inf);
}
```

in Broadcastreceiver class:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    String intentAction = intent.getAction();
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    String sUri = uri.toString();
    Uri alertUri = Uri.parse(sUri);

    Cursor alertCursor = cr.query(alertUri, ALERT_PROJECTION,
            null /* selection */, null, null /* sort order */);
```

but I have an error when cr.query:

unknown URL content://com.android.calendar/1373401980000

Answer (score 5):

The appended ID is not the eventID but rather the alarmTime.
See how the alarm broadcast is created here:
[scheduleAlarm()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/provider/CalendarContract.java#CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.scheduleAlarm%28android.content.Context,android.app.AlarmManager,long%29)

You can get the alarmTime by using:

```
String alarmTime = uri.getLastPathSegment();
```

This you can then use to query the CalendarAlerts:

```
 String[] projection = new String[] {
          CalendarAlerts.EVENT_ID
  };

 String selection = CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.ALARM_TIME + "=?";

 Cursor c = cr.query(CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.CONTENT_URI_BY_INSTANCE, 
          projection, 
          selection, 
          new String[] {alarmTime},
          null);

...
```